# How to get Nsight EE to compile with -dc flag?

Tags: c++, eclipse, cuda, makefile, nsight

I'm trying to compile a CUDA application with Nsight that compiles `.cpp` files to `.o` files then links the main application.  I'm basing my build off the NVIDIA "Parallel for All" example [Separate Compilation and Linking of CUDA C++ Device Code](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/)  and its [Makefile](https://github.com/parallel-forall/code-samples/blob/master/posts/separate-compilation-linking/makefile):

```
objects = main.o particle.o v3.o

all: $(objects)
        nvcc -arch=sm_20 $(objects) -o app

%.o: %.cpp
        nvcc -x cu -arch=sm_20 -I. -dc $< -o $@

clean:
        rm -f *.o app
```

When I copy my code into a new directory and use that Makefile (adapted to my filenames and other flags, of course), everything works fine.

But I can't figure out how to get the same options into Eclipse and as such the build always fails with the following errors:

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin/nvcc -G -g -O0 -std=c++11 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50  -odir "src" -M -o "src/Object.d" "../src/Object.cpp"
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin/nvcc -G -g -O0 -std=c++11 --compile  -x c++ -o  "src/Object.o" "../src/Object.cpp"

../src/kernels.cu:31:12: error: ‘blockIdx’ was not declared in this scope
#... lots more "no one told me this was CUDA" errors

../src/Object.cpp:125:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘<’ token
#... can't call CUDA kernels from cpp either ...
```

My project files' relevant includes are are:

Object.cpp:

```
#include "Object.h"
#include "kernels.cu"
```

main.cpp: (same error with fname as main.cu)

```
#include "Object.h"
```

kernels.cu:

```
#include "Object.h"
```

Object.h:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
```

The code compiles fine with the custom makefile.  The missing piece appears to be the `-dc` (device code) flag but I don't know how to enable it in Nsight Eclipse edition.  I know I can create a Makefile project, but I'd really prefer to do it from within Eclipse so that all the introspection works right etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, though I still don't entirely understand it... 
It seems that the `-x c++` was the key flag, not `-dc`.

The default build settings of Nsight Eclipse work correctly when the files are renamed as follows:

<strike>Object.cpp</strike> **Object.cu**:

```
#include "Object.h"
#include "kernels.cuh"
```

main.cpp: (main.cu is also good)

```
#include "Object.h"
```

<strike>kernels.cu</strike> **kernels.cuh**:

```
#include "Object.h"
```

Object.h:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
```

Apparently `.cu` files are compiled to `.o` files with `-x cu` (language CUDA) and then linked but `.cpp` files are compiled with language `-x c++` and therefore do not see all of the CUDA markup. The `main.cpp` file has no actual CUDA in it so it doesn't matter.

Without renaming the `kernels.cu` to `kernels.cuh` build fails with multiple definition errors because it's compiled twice.

The current configuration appears to work, I hope this is helpful to someone.  I really wish there was some clear documentation or settings on how file extensions affect build rules in Nsight...